# one link to multiple images

Tags: html, image

This is probably going to seem like a stupid question and I've probably glossed over something and missed the answer but is it possible to have one link which will lead to multiple images or an image directory?

I am making a website for a restaurant and ideally I would like a textual link for the menus (each of which are comprised off 3+ images).

Initially I created a separate page for each menu with an image gallery in it and the link pointing to the respective page but due to the restrictions off needing a user input event to make the gallery full screen I decided against using this idea.

I am currently using I frames for the menus but they don't fit in as nice as I would like with the design off the website and I am running into issues with them going full screen on iOS mobile.

Comment: This is a fairly broad question, as there are many ways to achieve your solution. Why not use the image-gallery plugin on the same side with the button and open the full-screen gallery when the link to the menus is clicked?

Comment: @Capricorn That should work perfectly thanks